# call a specific module using the module name as an argument to the main program

Tags: python, module, arguments

What I would like achieve is this.
Have a series of small modules in there own module directory.
Each module supplies the same function.
Import all the modules in the main program.
The have the main program called with a module name and have this return the value from the module.

```
import worker_modules
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='download a file through cURL')
parser.add_argument(
    'module', help='module to work on')
args = parser.parse.args()
module = args.module
result = module.command(extra args not shown)
```

the result fails as it thinks module has no attr command.

Is there a way tho achieve this - I dont want to dynamically load the module as I want to have this built as a static file.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at imported modules using `sys.modules`

```
import sys

# parser code...

module = args.module
result = sys.modules[module].command()
```

This allows you to import all the modules needed at the beginning without dynamically importing them. When a module is imported it is added to the `sys.modules` dict.